# Rails and jQuery - How to display a date as same for all time zones?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, graph, timezone

In rails 4 app, I am creating a data and trying to display as graph. When timezone changes then date also will get change, I want date(created date) should be same for all timezone while displaying it.

In database `:created_at => Thu, 28 May 2020 02:12:40 EDT -04:00` but in graph `May 27` is displaying. `'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` time zone is using now.

In jQuery:

```
d = new Date(1590624000 * 1000)
$.plot.formatDate(d, '%b %d')
```

How can I fix this issue which should work for all timezone? Whether while saving a data or while displaying it (jQuery side)?

Comment: Save the date in UTC on the server then convert it to local time zone when read on the client

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, without touching the back-end is it possible to fix it in front-end itself? Moreover back-end date is correct one only front-end it is the issue.

Comment: Sure, but it would be a hacky workaround. Using UTC as the primary date format is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: How it is possible? jQuery will fetch current timezone(set it in system) right, so based on it date will display in graph too.